# Does Twilio's API provide the carrier's name for incoming SMS messages?

Tags: sms, twilio

Is this possible and is it possible to have it POSTED along with the SMSMessage to an endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Twilio doesn't provide that information. Part of the goal of the Twilio API is that you shouldn't have to worry about that as it's not relevant to actually delivering the message.. it's like knowing your users' ISP.

*Disclosure: Twilio employee*

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do!

If you are [using lookup](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) to get the carrier to send Mobile Topup to, you require the carrier name. Actually, the thing you will need is the mapping of all possible carrier names that Twilio can produce, so you can map them to our own internal carrier list.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to list a carrier when attempting to verify many accounts. So even though Twilio did not anticipate this it is indeed needed. For example try verifying your facebook account. There you are required to list a mobile carrier...

Comment: That's because most sites don't use a true SMS message, instead they use an email that behaves like an SMS. It's usually of the phonenumber@carrier.net format. The problem is that it is as reliable as email with respect to delivery. Also, if you push a lot of traffic this way, carriers have a habit of blacklisting you. Yes, it's happened to me. :(